# Remove gradient/Gloss from UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am customizing the `UITabBar`. I used my custom image in `UITabBarItem`. The problem is whether there is a gradient/gloss on the item. I checked Apple's app Store didn't had any of this glossy effect on its `UITabBarItem`. How can i remove gradient from `UITabBarItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put clear image as `yourImage', it may help you

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage {yourImage}]]
```

**Edit**
 i just googled it and found lot of similar questions. You can also try below code of lines

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tappbarimage.png"]];
```

You'll have to provide the images yourself to the UITabBarItem with using this tabbarMethod [`setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/setFinishedSelectedImage%3awithFinishedUnselectedImage%3a).

There's no other way to affect the processing it does to the images besides changing the color of the gradient with UITabBar's [`selectedImageTintColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBar/selectedImageTintColor) appearance property.

Comment: I need to remove gradient from from UITabBarItem, this code will cause selection to be clear not my requirement

Comment: setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: does this trick thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: This helped me to hide shadow from my non-standartized height tab bar:                                                       [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];