# UITabBarItem delete glossy from image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image]

You can see that house picture with shadow and like prerendered icon. How can I delete this effect?

Comment: You need to change image of your UITabBarItem which has not glossy effect :)

Comment: yes iPatel is correct....

Comment: my image without glossy

Comment: @MaximusAlarmus... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979121/remove-gradient-gloss-from-uitabbaritem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both finished and unfinished images on your UITabBarItem otherwise framework will automatically add the shine on it. Here is how you can do it.

```
[barItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
```

Please note that both finished and unfinished images are same.